# How how to transform an R file into an R markdown file in a simple way?

Tags: r, r-markdown, transform

I know how to create a Rmarkdow file but in case I have a large R file with a lot of codes and comments, I need to find a simple way to transform the R file into an R markdown file without having to lose the time in copy paste all that I have done. The resulted Rmarkdown has the comments without the # sign.

A simple example is

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

# create a dataframe

df = data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:10], y = 1:10)
df

# create a plot

ggplot(df)+aes(x=x,y=y,fill=x)+
  geom_col()
```

Comment: See `?knitr::stitch`.

Comment: can you show me how to apply it please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stitch` in the **knitr** package. For example, save this file under the name ***script.R***:

```r
## title: A test script for the function stitch()
## author: Yihui Xie
set.seed(1121)
(x = rnorm(20))
mean(x);var(x)
boxplot(x)
hist(x, main = '')
```

Then run `stitch("script.R")`.

It's also possible to add some comments in the script which will become chunk options in the **Rmd** file, for example:

```r
## title: A test script for the function stitch()
## author: Yihui Xie
set.seed(1121)
x <- rnorm(20)

## ---- mylabel, echo=FALSE
mean(x);var(x)

boxplot(x)
hist(x, main = '')
```

To get a more elaborate **Rmd** file, you can use `spin` instead of `stitch`. See [here](https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/stitch/) for an example.